# Can I get just the EPUB file from the Kobo store?

Tags: epub, download, kobo-store

I am interested in a DRM-free EPUB ([Switching Social](https://www.kobo.com/us/en/ebook/the-switching-social-handbook)) available only on the Kobo store.

If I purchase it, can I download *just* the EPUB file, without having to use the Kobo app? I'm quite happy with my existing EPUB reader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Once you've purchased the book, you can go to "My Books" and find the one you want to download. Below the thumbnail of the book cover there is a "..." menu which looks like this when expanded:

[image: Cover with action menu]

Click "Download" and you'll be presented with a dialog:

[image: Download dialog box]

Now you can load the downloaded epub on any reader you like.